# Error cannot generate SQL for Custom SQL at BO

Tags: sql, business-objects

I'm using business object 4 and currently developing a report using custom SQL. Total object and data type selected using custom sql and object at webbi already the same. But when I try to validate webbi always sends error `cannot generate sql`.

How to fix this and what is the cause of this error?

My sql syntax is as follows:

```
select * from( 
    SELECT
    DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN TRIM(msv26A.PROJECT_NO) IS NULL THEN msvPRJ.PROJECT_NO ELSE msv26A.PROJECT_NO END,
        msv660.PROJ_DESC,
        msv26A.PO_NO,
        msv200.SUPPLIER_NAME,
        msv26A.SUPPLIER_NO,
        msv260.EXT_INV_NO,
        msv200.SUP_TYPEX1,
        msv260.CURRENCY_TYPE,
        msv000_DC0001.DSTRCT_CODE,
        msv000_DC0001.DSTRCT_NAME,
        msv260.PMT_STATUS,
        msv260.DUE_DATE,
        msv260.INV_DATE,
        msv260.FOR_INV_ORIG,
        msv260.LOC_INV_ORIG,
        msv260.FOR_INV_AMD,
        msv260.LOC_INV_AMD,
        msv260.AMT_RETAINED,
        msv260.PRESC_PMT_AMT,
        msv260.PP_AMT_LOC,
        msv260_1.AMT_PAID_FOR,
        msv071.REF_CODE,
        CASE WHEN EMV260_AGING_RETENTION.LOC_INV_RETENTION IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE EMV260_AGING_RETENTION.LOC_INV_RETENTION END,
        CASE WHEN EMV260_AGING_RETENTION.FOR_INV_RETENTION IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE EMV260_AGING_RETENTION.FOR_INV_RETENTION END
    FROM
        msv200 RIGHT OUTER JOIN msv26A ON (msv26A.SUPPLIER_NO = msv200.SUPPLIER_NO)
        INNER JOIN msv000_DC0001 ON (msv000_DC0001.DSTRCT_CODE = msv26A.DSTRCT_CODE)
        INNER JOIN msv260 ON (msv26A.DSTRCT_CODE = msv260.DSTRCT_CODE AND msv26A.SUPPLIER_NO = msv260.SUPPLIER_NO AND msv26A.INV_NO = msv260.INV_NO)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN msvPRJ ON (msvPRJ.DSTRCT_CODE = msv26A.DSTRCT_CODE AND TRIM(msvPRJ.PO_NO) = trim(msv26A.PO_NO))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN msv660 ON (msv26A.DSTRCT_CODE = msv660.DSTRCT_CODE AND (CASE WHEN TRIM(msv26A.PROJECT_NO) IS NULL
            THEN msvPRJ.PROJECT_NO ELSE msv26A.PROJECT_NO END) = msv660.PROJECT_NO)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN msv260  msv260_1 ON (msv260_1.DSTRCT_CODE = msv260.DSTRCT_CODE and msv260_1.SUPPLIER_NO = msv260.SUPPLIER_NO and msv260_1.INV_NO = msv260.INV_NO)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN msv071 ON (msv071.ENTITY_VALUE=msv260.SUPPLIER_NO AND msv071.ENTITY_TYPE='SUP')
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT A.DSTRCT_CODE,
                A.SUPPLIER_NO,
                A.ORIG_INV_NO,
                SUM(CASE WHEN A.LOC_INV_AMD <> 0
                    THEN A.LOC_INV_AMD ELSE A.LOC_INV_ORIG END) LOC_INV_RETENTION,
                SUM(CASE WHEN A.FOR_INV_AMD <> 0
                    THEN A.FOR_INV_AMD ELSE A.FOR_INV_ORIG END) FOR_INV_RETENTION
                FROM msv260 A
                WHERE A.FULL_PER_LOADED <= @prompt('Enter Full Period(From):','A','260\Full Per Loaded',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User :3) 
                    AND TRIM(A.PMT_STATUS)  >=  '30' AND  TRIM(A.PMT_STATUS) <= '55'
                GROUP BY
                A.DSTRCT_CODE,
                A.SUPPLIER_NO,
                A.ORIG_INV_NO) EMV260_AGING_RETENTION
       ON (msv260.DSTRCT_CODE = EMV260_AGING_RETENTION.DSTRCT_CODE
           AND msv260.SUPPLIER_NO = EMV260_AGING_RETENTION.SUPPLIER_NO
           AND msv260.INV_NO = EMV260_AGING_RETENTION.ORIG_INV_NO)
  WHERE

 msv26A.DSTRCT_CODE  in  @prompt('Enter value(s) for Dstrct Code:','A','msv26a\Dstrct Code',Multi,Free,Persistent,,User:5)

   AND
   TRIM(msv260.PMT_STATUS)  >=  '30' AND  TRIM(msv260.PMT_STATUS) <= '55'
   AND
   (
      ( msv260.FULL_PER_LOADED  <= @prompt('Enter Full Period(From):','A','260\Full Per Loaded',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User :3)  
      AND msv260.FULL_PER_PAID  =  '000000' )
       OR
      ( msv260.FULL_PER_PAID  > @prompt('Enter Full Period(To):','A','260\Full Per Paid',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User :4) 
      AND msv260.FULL_PER_LOADED  <=  @prompt('Enter Full Period(From):','A','260\Full Per Loaded',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User :3) )
    )
AND msv260.CURRENCY_TYPE <> ' '
ORDER BY msv000_DC0001.DSTRCT_CODE, msv260.SUPPLIER_NO, msv200.SUP_TYPEX1, msv260.CURRENCY_TYPE)
WHERE (DSTRCT_CODE,SUPPLIER_NO,EXT_INV_NO) IN (SELECT
       DISTINCT DSTRCT_CODE,SUPPLIER_NO,EXT_INV_NO FROM msv900
WHERE DSTRCT_CODE in @prompt('Enter value(s) for Dstrct Code:','A','msv900\Dstrct Code',Multi,Free,Persistent,,User:1)
AND FULL_PERIOD <= @prompt('Enter Full Period(From):','A','msv900\Full Period',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User :2) 
AND ACCOUNT_CODE IN ('21101')
)
ORDER BY
PROJECT_NO,
SUPPLIER_NO
```

Comment: Looks like a SQL Server query. Please do two things: 1. Add the SQL Server tag if correct. 2. Find a SQL Server query tool, run the query and get a useful error message.

Comment: At a glance, it could be `ORDER BY msv000_DC0001.DSTRCT_CODE, msv260.SUPPLIER_NO, msv200.SUP_TYPEX1, msv260.CURRENCY_TYPE` as I think you get an error if you have an `ORDER BY` inside a subselect. It doesn't do anything as it is ordered afterwards anyway.